# docker-compose failed searching for an environment file for a service I don't want to start

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file like: -

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - ./.development.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  mock-websocket-server:
    image: node:18-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./.socket.env
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    command: node /usr/src/mockWebsocketServer.js
```

I want to only start the `mock-websocket-server` service. In this specific environment the `postgres` service is not required.

When I execute `docker-compose up -d mock-websocket-server` in an environment where `.development.env` does not exist (this is my use case), then docker-compose fails with the following error (I shortened the paths in the example error): -

```
Failed to load .../.development.env: open .../.development.env: no such file or directory
```

If I put `.development.env` in the codebase in this specific environment, then the error goes away. But I do not want to put this file in the codebase.

I am expecting docker-compose to ignore env files that are not needed for the docker-compose services I am trying to build.